# How to get a WPF application to print out multiple values?

Tags: c#, wpf

This project opens a dialog box to let users pick courses.  The output it produces now only gives me a single course to choose from.  How can I get the course class to display all courses?

This is the mainWindow file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace CreateClassesObjs
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        Course choice;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Course course1 = new Course();
            Course course2 = new Course();
            Course course3 = new Course();
            Course course4 = new Course();
            Course course5 = new Course();
            Course course6 = new Course();
            Course course7 = new Course();

            course1.setName("IT 145");
            course2.setName("IT 200");
            course3.setName("IT 201");
            course4.setName("IT 270");
            course5.setName("IT 315");
            course6.setName("IT 328");
            course7.setName("IT 330");



            this.comboBox.Items.Add(course1);
            this.comboBox.Items.Add(course2);
            this.comboBox.Items.Add(course3);
            this.comboBox.Items.Add(course4);
            this.comboBox.Items.Add(course5);
            this.comboBox.Items.Add(course6);
            this.comboBox.Items.Add(course7);
        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            choice = (Course)(this.comboBox.SelectedItem);
            this.listBox.Items.Add(choice);
        }

    }
}
```

And this is my file.

```
namespace CreateClassesObjs
{
    internal class Course

    {
        static string name;

        public Course()
        {

        }

        public string setName(string choice)
        {
            name = choice;

            return name.ToString();

        }

        /*
        public string retrieveName(string choice)
        {
            name = choice;
            return name.setName();
        }
        */

        public override string ToString()
        {


            return name;

        }

    }
}
```

This is my output:
[image]

It's only printing the last value.  When it's supposed to print all of these;

```
course1.setName("IT 145");
course2.setName("IT 200");
course3.setName("IT 201");
course4.setName("IT 270");
course5.setName("IT 315");
course6.setName("IT 328");
course7.setName("IT 330");
```

ToString is supposed to get all the previous strings.

Answer (score 1):

**Short/quick answer** (sticking to code behind):

A ComboBox only supports single item to be selected.
By replacing it with an ListBox you can configure it to accept more than one selected item. These are available in the SelectedItems property.

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach(var choice in this.listBoxSource.SelectedItems.OfType<Course>())
    {
        this.listBox.Items.Add(choice);
    }
}
```

**Long answer** (going the MVVM way):

Implement INotifyPropertyChanged on the Course class to support proper data binding.

Add a Selected property to the Course class.
Add a DataTemplate to the Source list box that displays a course including a Checkbox for the Selected Property.

This will allow you to use data binding because you can now check the Courses themselves to find out if their are selected. This results in less code behind the UI which makes it easier to change, maintain and (unit)test.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I'm not supposed to edit that file at all only the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I was able to make the program work.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace CreateClassesObjs
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        Course choice;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Course course1 = new Course("IT 145");
            Course course2 = new Course("IT 200");
            Course course3 = new Course("IT 201");
            Course course4 = new Course("IT 270");
            Course course5 = new Course("IT 315");
            Course course6 = new Course("IT 328");
            Course course7 = new Course("IT 330");

            course1.setName("IT 145");
            course2.setName("IT 200");
            course3.setName("IT 201");
            course4.setName("IT 270");
            course5.setName("IT 315");
            course6.setName("IT 328");
            course7.setName("IT 330");

            this.comboBox.Items.Add(course1);
            this.comboBox.Items.Add(course2);
            this.comboBox.Items.Add(course3);
            this.comboBox.Items.Add(course4);
            this.comboBox.Items.Add(course5);
            this.comboBox.Items.Add(course6);
            this.comboBox.Items.Add(course7);
        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            choice = (Course)(this.comboBox.SelectedItem);
            this.listBox.Items.Add(choice);
        }

        class Course
        {
            private string name = "";


            public Course(string name)
            {
                this.name = name;
            }

            public void setName(string name)
            {
                this.name = name;
            }

            public string getName()
            {
                return name;
            }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return getName();
            }
        }
    }
}
```